# How to create MongoDB views in PHP using MongoDB\Client() library?

Tags: php, mongodb, view

I'm using following:
PHP 7.2
MongoDB 3.4
Pecl 1.5.2

I'm working on a Laravel project. It uses MongoDB as database. I have few collections on which I have to create Mongo Views using Laravel migration. I was wondering whether its possible to create Mongodb Views using PHP. Currently I have a work around. I have created a JavaScript file which has MongoDB db.createView() query in it. It also takes view name and collection name as parameters. Following is my work around. $db has database name, $view has view name, $collection has collection name and $script has the path to the JavaScript file. This code I'm writing in migration class's up() method.

```html
$cmd = "mongo $db --eval \"var view='$view', collection='$collection'\" $script";
exec($cmd);
```

In my Javascript file, I have code something like following

```html
db.createView(view, collection, <aggregate query>);
```

So as everyone can see, I'm running terminal command from PHP to make views. So is there any PHP function in mongo library to make mongo views?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please start by reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Otherwise for now it's be nice if you'd explain your problem more thoughtfully while giving sample examples as well as what you've tried so far to resolve your problem.

Comment: you should elaborate it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using mongo with Laravel, I'm going to assume you're using `jenssegers/mongodb` to use it with Eloquent.

So, let's assume you have your mongo database set up as your `'mongodb'` database connection. You need the `MongoDB\Database` for your database. You can get this with:

```php
$mongo = app('db')->connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB();
```

Of course, if you're not using `jenssegers/mongodb`, you can still do the same thing with `mongodb/mongodb` as well.

```php
$mongo = (new MongoDB\Client)->selectDatabase($db);
```

This has a method called `command` (see https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/method/MongoDBDatabase-command/), which corresponds to the `db.runCommand` method from the mongo cli. `db.createView` calls that method (see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/#db.createView)

So, you can use `$mongo->command` to create the view like this:

```php
$mongo->command([
    'create' => $view,
    'viewOn' => $collection,
    'pipeline' => $aggregateQuery,
    'collation' => ['locale' => 'en'],
]);
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks for the solution. This worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library [mongoPhpLibrary](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library)

This will make your work easy